# How to use CAGradientLayer?

Tags: iphone, core-animation, calayer

I'm getting up to speed with the new APIs introduced in OS 3.0, especially the cool new improvements to Core Animation (mostly on CALayer etc...). Now I'm trying to figure out how to use CAGradientLayer. It looks simple at first, but the NSArray it requires for the colors property must contain CGColorRef (according to the header file). I've tried casting to (id), but then the NSArray seems to contain NSCFType objects, which doesn't sound good.

Anybody figured how to use it or could point to some good code samples?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though the NSCFType objects in the array "don't sound good", you are supposed to use CGColorRefs directly in the array.  The same principle applies here as for the [animation question I asked a while back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518192/how-do-you-explicitly-animate-a-calayers-backgroundcolor).  The examples I've seen for using this class all employ arrays of CGColorRefs.

Comment: +1 for using an answer to your own question to answer another